# react native crash when tapping navigation button too fast

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I used react navigation 4.0.10 and it's little bit complicated app with nested navigator. Currently it's performing relatively well except that When I try to navigate it very fast, it will crash. The error message is

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state')

The structure is

```
-bottomTapNavigator(Home, Scan; Scan is a stackNavigator)
 --HomeScreen
 --ScanNavigator(stackNavigator, parent for ScanScreen and JourneyNavigator[tabNavigator])
   ---ScanScreen(Real page, initial screen of ScanNavigator, having buttons to navigate(HomeScreen) and navigate(JourneyNavigator))
   ---JourneyNavigator(TabNavigator, including ScreenTest1 and ScreenTest2; having header with back button navigate(ScanScreen) for both ScreenTest1 and ScreenTest2;)
      ---ScreenTest1(Real page)
      ---ScreenTest2(Real page, does not matter in this case)
```

what I do is tap ScanNavigator[ScanScreen]->ScreenTest1->ScanScreen(**tap navigation button quickly here**)->HomeScreen

In such case, the app will crash. If i do it with normal pace then it's fine.

Any help or direction is welcome.

**EDIT**

> I'm 100 percent certain it's something to do with **resetOnBlur** setting. When it set to false, the issue gone. Help please.